# In AaAaAA, is there a way to see how many levels you've unlocked or stars collected?

Tags: a-reckless-disregard-for-gravity

Is there a way (even if it's a hack into save file way) to see how many of the 81 levels I have unlocked, or how many stars I have in total in AaAaAA!!! - A Reckless Disregard for Gravity?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, while you can see how many stars you've earned for individual levels on the level select screen, there is no quick way to check how many stars you have total. You would need to check each level individually and add up your star count manually.

[image: Level select screen showing star ranking for an individual level]

The same also applies to the semi-sequel *AaaaaAAaaaAAAaaAAAAaAAAAA!!! for the Awesome*.